# Can you use variables inside $'...' in bash?

Tags: bash, quoting

I have tried the following:

```
myprogram $'Hello $HOME'
```

But it did not work (the command line argument received by `myprogram` was `Hello $HOME`, and not the value of `$HOME`).

Comment: `myprogram "Hello $HOME"`?

Comment: @ilkkachu: Good catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from interpreting the C-style backslash-escapes, `$'...'` works like a single-quoted string. At least Bash's manual mentions this, right at the end of [the page on "ANSI-C quoting"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting):

> The expanded result is single-quoted, as if the dollar sign had not been present.

So, no. That's probably why they chose to use single-quotes for that (or the other way around), though I don't know about the history of the feature.

You'll have to use double-quotes, and change the quotes as necessary. i.e.

```
$ myprogram "Hello $HOME"
```

or with a tab mixed in

```
$ myprogram $'Hello\t'"$HOME"
```

Comment: The feature comes from ksh93. Added to bash in 2.0 (1996), zsh in 3.1.5 (1998) mksh in R39b (2010)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I would have guessed ksh. I mostly wondered if there was a conscious reason to make it a variant of single-quoting instead of double-quoting. Maybe expanding variables is more useful in strings translated with `$""` so double-quotes got used for that? But it doesn't matter enough that I would start looking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write it as

```
$ myprogram "Hello $HOME"
```

Bash will preserve the literal meaning of anything enclosed within double quotes except $,`(back-tick) or .So Here it considers "Hello" as the value while $Hello preserves its value as a variable.